# Ajuda com organização de código de projetos

Tags: php, mysql

Entrei num projeto escrito em php que no início não tinha idéia da proporção que iria tomar. Então já escrevi tanto código que até eu estou um pouco perdido para localizar alguns problemas.

Pra fazer o projeto, a medida que fui realizando eu também estava aprendendo sobre a linguagem, mas sem nenhuma noção de como iria ficar a organização.

Padronizei algumas coisas que nem sem se ficariam da forma correta.

Dessa forma:
Os arquivos com o código html estão soltos na raiz da pasta.
Os que realizam alguma lógica estão na pasta controles.
Os que tem as funções que buscam, inserem, alteram e apagam registros no banco de dados estão na pasta classes.
E uma pasta api que fiz para retornar um Json quando utilizar um aplicativo móvel.

Até aí tudo bem, acho que fica até organizado. Mas alguns arquivos das classes por exemplo estão grandes demais.

Ex (essa classe possui 440 linhas e subindo):

```
function inserePedido($id_cliente){
    $query = "INSERT INTO pedido (id_cliente) VALUES ({$id_cliente});";
    $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
    return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function inserePedidoItem($cliente,$produto,$tipo_cobranca,$id_tabela,$preco,$sequencia,$vendedor,$data,$cod_barras){
  $uuid=uniqid(rand(), true);
  $data_vencimento = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+20 days",strtotime($data)));
  $query = "INSERT INTO pedido_item (id_cliente,id_produto,sequencia,tamanho,
  id_vendedor,preco,situacao,data_hora,data_vencimento,cod_barras,tipo_cobranca,id_tabela,uuid) VALUES (
    {$cliente},{$produto['id']},{$sequencia},{$produto['tamanho']},
    {$vendedor},{$preco},6,'{$data}','{$data_vencimento}','{$cod_barras}',{$tipo_cobranca},{$id_tabela},'{$uuid}');";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function inserePedidoItemReserva($cliente,$produto,$tipo_cobranca,$id_tabela,
$preco,$sequencia,$vendedor,$data,$cod_barras){
  $uuid=uniqid(rand(), true);
  $data_vencimento = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+20 days",strtotime($data)));
  $query = "INSERT INTO pedido_item (id_cliente,id_produto,sequencia,tamanho,
  id_vendedor,preco,situacao,data_hora,data_vencimento,cod_barras,tipo_cobranca,id_tabela,uuid)
  VALUES ({$cliente},{$produto['id']},{$sequencia},{$produto['tamanho']},
  {$vendedor},{$preco},15,'{$data}','{$data_vencimento}','{$cod_barras}',{$tipo_cobranca},{$id_tabela},'{$uuid}');";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function inserePedidoItemCodigo($cliente,$produto,$tipo_cobranca,$id_tabela,
$preco,$sequencia,$vendedor,$data,$cod_barras){
  $uuid=uniqid(rand(), true);
  $data_vencimento = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+20 days",strtotime($data)));
  $query = "INSERT INTO pedido_item (id_cliente,id_produto,sequencia,tamanho,
  id_vendedor,preco,situacao,data_hora,data_vencimento,cod_barras,tipo_cobranca,id_tabela,uuid)
  VALUES ({$cliente},{$produto['id']},{$sequencia},{$produto['tamanho']},{$vendedor},
  {$preco},4,'{$data}','{$data_vencimento}','{$cod_barras}',{$tipo_cobranca},{$id_tabela},'{$uuid}');";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function inserePedidoParcialItemCodigo($cliente,$produto,$tipo_cobranca,$id_tabela,
$preco,$sequencia,$vendedor,$data,$cod_barras){
  $uuid=uniqid(rand(), true);
  $data_vencimento = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+20 days",strtotime($data)));
  $query = "INSERT INTO pedido_item (id_cliente,id_produto,sequencia,tamanho,confirmado,
  id_vendedor,preco,situacao,data_hora,data_vencimento,cod_barras,tipo_cobranca,id_tabela,uuid)
  VALUES ({$cliente},{$produto['id']},{$sequencia},{$produto['tamanho']},1,{$vendedor},
  {$preco},4,'{$data}','{$data_vencimento}','{$cod_barras}',{$tipo_cobranca},{$id_tabela},'{$uuid}');";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function inserePedidoProdutoDevolucao($cliente,$produto,$tipo_cobranca,
$id_tabela,$preco,$sequencia,$vendedor,$data,$cod_barras){
  $uuid=uniqid(rand(), true);
  $query = "INSERT INTO pedido_item (id_cliente,id_produto,sequencia,tamanho,
  id_vendedor,preco,situacao,data_hora,cod_barras,tipo_cobranca,id_tabela,uuid,confirmado)
  VALUES ({$cliente},{$produto['id']},{$sequencia},{$produto['tamanho']},
  {$vendedor},{$preco},8,'{$data}','{$cod_barras}',{$tipo_cobranca},{$id_tabela},'{$uuid}',1);";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function removePedidoProdutoUnidade($id_cliente,$sequencia){
  $query = "DELETE FROM pedido_item WHERE id_cliente={$id_cliente}
  AND sequencia={$sequencia} AND (situacao = 6 OR situacao = 4 OR situacao=15);";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function removePedidoItemDevolucao($id_cliente){
  $query = "DELETE FROM pedido_item WHERE id_cliente={$id_cliente} AND (situacao = 8 OR situacao = 12);";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function excluirProdutoPedidoTotal($id_cliente,$id_produto,$data){
    $query = "DELETE FROM pedido_item WHERE id_cliente={$id_cliente}
    AND DATE(data_hora)=DATE('{$data}') AND id_produto={$id_produto}
    AND (situacao = 6 OR situacao = 4 OR SITUACAO=15);";
    $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
    return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function removerPedidoUnidade($id_cliente,$sequencia){
    $query = "DELETE FROM pedido_item WHERE id_cliente={$id_cliente}
    AND sequencia={$sequencia}";
    $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
    return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function removerPedidoNaoConfirmados($cliente){
  $query = "DELETE FROM pedido_item WHERE id_cliente={$cliente}
  AND confirmado=0";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  return $conexao->exec($query);
}

function finalizarPedidoMaisTarde($cliente){
  $query = "UPDATE pedido set finalizar = 1;";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  $conexao->exec($query);
}

function finalizarPedidoMaisTardeNao($cliente){
  $query = "UPDATE pedido set finalizar = 0;";
  $conexao = Conexao::criarConexao();
  $conexao->exec($query);
}...
```

Existe algum padrão de projeto que posso aplicar que é recomendado nesses casos, ou algum sugestão para abordar mais consultas de forma mais simples.
Eu sei que existem alguns frameworks como laravel, mas não tenho mais tempo para aprender e fazer a conversão.
E estou muito preocupado com manutenção do código.

Comment: Acho que você está misturando pedidos com produtos. É melhor separá-los. Já ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Eu também sou iniciante na linguagem e o que me ajudou bastante na organização foi a utilização do padrão MVC, não é a unica forma de fazer nem a melhor, mas em questão de organização ajuda bastante. Nele você pode organizar o sistema por camadas, e para cada camada você faz uma pasta deixando os arquivos html no diretório raiz.
Exemplo:

```
Patas
CLASS // aqui ficam suas classes bases como, Pedido, Produto e etc;
DAO //  aqui você faz a comunicação com o banco de dados utilizando as classes bases
CONTROLLERS //  aqui você passa os dados da interface para a DAO e vice e versa.
```

[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/conceito-de-mvc-e-sua-funcionalidade-usando-o-php/22324)

Comment: Blz. Obrigado. Vou dar uma estudada. Passa um tempo, o código fica grande demais e até começo a me perder. Imagina quem pegar esse código pra continuar o trabalho. rs. Abraço